# Regarding http response appending extra characters in ie

Tags: java, http

I am facing the problem with http response in IE browser in chrome it works fine.
When I am setting HttpResponse as:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWrite().write("xyz");
response.getWrite().flush();
response.getWrite().close();
```

The response in browser displayed is like:
3 xyz0
numerical character is appended at the begening and end of the string.

How to remove extra characters 3 and 0 , issue exists only in IE

Comment: Try writing valid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the [Content-length](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength%28int%29) header of the response. Seems like your servlet container are sending the response data as [chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), the characters "3" (the number of the octects of data in the chunk expressed in hexadecimal value) and "0" (last chunk) are markers for the received data when is no `content-length` header present in the response, try this

```
String content = "xyz";
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentLength(content.getBytes().length);
response.getWriter().write(content);
response.getWriter().flush();
response.getWriter().close();
```

Comment: we already tried for the same setting the content length but still issue exist

Comment: Could you please post the complete response received by IE with headers and data?